# Spring Boot Bucket4j customize http response body when rate limit exceeds

Tags: spring-boot, rate-limiting

I have configured API rate limiting using Spring Boot Bucket4j starter(`bucket4j-spring-boot-starter`) with ehcache. It returns 429 response with following message when rate limit exceeds but I would like to dynamically customize the response body. Lets say I would like to add timestamp in the response. How can I do that? I am setting the response body in `application.properties` file:

```
bucket4j.filters[0].http-response-body={ "status": 429, "error": "Too Many Requests", "message": "API rate limit exceeded" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the current starter version, v0.5.2, it seems not supporting dynamically customize the response body. In the filter source code(https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/com/giffing/bucket4j/spring/boot/starter/filter/servlet/ServletRequestFilter.java) you can see that the response body seems only determined by the config. And they are not using exceptions.

But still there is one slight tricky way you can do to send the dynamic response body.

1. set the response body to an empty string
2. create a filter that has a higher order than the bucket4j one, and check if the status code is 429. If it is, create your own response body and append to the writer.

*you can also set some headers in that filter if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiter just throw usual exception, it means you can add your own custom error message handler and rewrite response in this handler as you want. See more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api)